# Cardinality of a set defined in Royden

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

On page 5 of Royden, Fitzpatrick's real analysis, the book defined cardinality of the set in the following way:

> Given a set $X$, the relation of equipotence (invertible map) is an equivalence relation on the collection of $2^X$ of all subsets of $X$. The equivalence class of a set with respect to the relation equipotence is called the **cardinality** of the set.

Suppose $X = \{a,b,c\}$, $2^X = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\},  \{a,b\}, \{b,c\},\{a,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$, with equipotence as the equivalence relation $R$, we see the quotient 
 set $2^X/R = \{\overline \emptyset, \overline{\{a\}}, \overline {\{a,b\}}, \overline{\{a,b,c\}}\}$ where the bar represents the equivalence class.

Is there a connection to the "size of a set"? I think this is how cardinality of a set is often defined as.

And is there another word that is often used for this definition instead of "cardinality"? And is this often used, I have never seen this.

Comment: Sets which are in the same equivalence class have the same size. This is a rigorous way to define (infinite) cardinality (which intuitively means size) without using ordinals and other set theoretic machinery which isn't needed in introductory real analysis. The analogous definition for finite sizes would be to define the the cardinality of {1,5,7} to be the class of all sets of the same size as {1,5,7} to avoid using the number THREE.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of this section Royden states that his intention is to describe concepts from set theory so that it will be plausible and to promote understanding; you can consult other source for a more rigorous treatment.

His definition of cardinality is certainly expedient. By starting with a 'universal' focus set $X$, he puts out the idea in a constructive way, distancing himself from more abstract/axiomatic approaches. Notice how he 'sneaks' "$2^X$" into the text with no comment. I glanced over the book and I would be surprised if he ever mentions the cardinality $2^{\Bbb N}$.

So, don't worry; you are studying real analysis and can profit without using high-precision set theoretic machinery.

By the way, I've recently been thinking that in the 21st Century, mathematicians should be able to assert that their working framework is

Circumspect Set Theory

Like Naive Set Theory from the 20th Century, but with the promise that they won't get too crazy and wild. [See Naive set_theory / Utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory#Utility).

Answer (score 0):

The best is to figure out an equivalence relation on $2^X$ such that the subsets of the "same size" form an equivalence class. Consider the relation $\sim$ on $2^X$ given by  $$\forall A,B\in 2^X:( A\sim B\iff \exists\ \text{a bijection } f:A\to B) .$$

Now you can easily verify that $\sim$ determines an equivalence relation on $2^X$ and the corresponding equivalence classes are families of sets of the "same size". We say $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if $A\sim B$.

The notion of "same size" is intuitively clear for at least the sets with a number of elements that you can count even if counting perpetuates or terminates at some point. But regarding the sets you cannot count the number of elements of, say for example the set of all real numbers, one must be silent about the "size". Nevertheless if it is stipulated that the existence of a bijection between two sets means that they are of the "same size" then we will be happy to say $\mathbb{R}$ and the interval $(0,1)$ have the "same size".